# Can anyone tell me the formula for this vector field?

Tags: vector-fields

## 3Blue1Brown's [video on curl](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eEwZeY51mT0)

[image]

$$V=\bigg[ \begin{array}{ccc}
P\left(x,y\right) \\
Q\left(x,y\right) \end{array} \bigg] $$

- $P$ gives you the **x** component at all points in space.
- $Q$ gives you the **y** component at any point in space.

## What is the explicit formula for the above vector field?

- vortexes at $(6,0)$, $(-6,0)$, $(0,6)$, $(0,-6)$
- and a source and a sink at the origin.
- symmetrical

Hints, links welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to be certain of the exact formula, but here's a general strategy for constructing this type of field.

1. Pick a vector field having a vortex at the origin, such as
   $$
   F(x, y) = \phi(x, y)(-y, x)
   $$
   for some real-valued function $\phi$. For example:

   - Taking $\phi \equiv 1$ gives the velocity field of a plane rotating counterclockwise about the origin at constant angular speed.
   - Taking $\phi(x, y) = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2}}}$ gives a vortex whose flow has unit velocity at each point (except the origin).
   - Taking $\phi(x, y) = \dfrac{1}{x^{2} + y^{2}}$ gives a vortex whose flow is incompressible.
2. If $(x_{0}, y_{0})$ is an arbitrary point, the field
   $$
   F_{(x_{0}, y_{0})}(x, y) = F(x - x_{0}, y - y_{0})
   \tag{2}
   $$
   has a vortex at $(x_{0}, y_{0})$.
3. Form the sum or difference of fields of the form (2), summing over each vortex location, and using a negative sign to change the direction of flow.

In the diagram,
$$
F(x, y) = \frac{2(-y, x)}{1 + \sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2}}},
$$
so the field plotted is
$$
G(x, y) = F(x - 6, y) + F(x + 6, 0) - F(x, y - 6) - F(x, y + 6).
$$
(Writing this out as a pair of component functions is left as a mildly masochistic exercise.)
[image: A vector field with four vortices]

Answer (score 0):

Working through Andrew D. Hwang's answer above:

$$F\left(x,y\right)=\left(\frac{2(-y)}{1+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},\frac{2(x)}{1+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)$$

> $$G\left(x,y\right)=\left(\frac{-2(y)}{1+\sqrt{(x-6)^2+(y)^2}}+\frac{-2(y)}{1+\sqrt{(x+6)^2+(y)^2}}-\frac{-2(y-6)}{1+\sqrt{(x)^2+(y-6)^2}}-\frac{-2(y+6)}{1+\sqrt{(x)^2+(y+6)^2}},\\
> \\
> \\
> \frac{-2(x-6)}{1+\sqrt{(x-6)^2+(y)^2}}\\
> \\
> +\frac{-2(x+6)}{1+\sqrt{(x+6)^2+(y)^2}}-\frac{-2(x)}{1+\sqrt{(x)^2+(y-6)^2}}-\frac{-2(x)}{1+\sqrt{(x)^2+(y+6)^2}}\right)$$

- first four terms give the **x** component
- the second four terms compute the **y** component

[image]